# How to plot each row in Pandas dataframe and color it by data from one column

Tags: python, pandas, graphics

I have pandas table that looks like:

```
| Sample | Type  | 1  | 2  | 3  | ...
| S1     | Type1 | 1  | 2  | 3  | ...
| S2     | Type2 | 5  | 6  | 7  | ...
| S3     | Type3 | 8  | 9  | 10 | ...
   ....
| S100   | Type3 | n  | n  | n  | ...
```

I want to plot multiple line plot where each line will color by type from 'Type' column (there are only three types). And Axis mast be the numbers from column names (1, 2, 3 ect)

I have tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925966/how-to-plot-each-pandas-row-as-a-line-plot), but because it plots each row, in the end I have more than 100 different colors.

here is [csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kBTVOX0UTifIhVMKjN0I--RA2b04pNMq/view?usp=sharing) with a toy example

That what I did based on the link with the solution above. The result is good apart the fact that I want to have only 3 line colors, based on 'Type' column

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
df = df.set_index('Type')
df = df.drop(columns='Sample')

ax = df.T.plot(figsize=(7, 6))
ax.set_ylabel('Absolute Power (log)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel('Frequencies', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` to draw a collection of lines then keep only one instance of each to build:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
colormap = {'type 1': 'red', 'type 2': 'green', 'type 3': 'blue'}
custom_lines = {}

for name, subdf in df.groupby(level='Type'):
    lines = ax.plot(subdf.T, label=name, color=colormap[name])
    custom_lines[name] = lines[0]

ax.set_ylabel('Absolute Power (log)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel('Frequencies', fontsize=12)

plt.legend(custom_lines.values(), custom_lines.keys())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]